# Is it possible to show some kind of warning if a prop value doesn't match a Regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Let's say I want `id` to be a string that also matches a Regex, for example `/^[A-Z]_[0-9]{4}$/`.

```
interface MyComponentProps {
   id: string
}

const MyComponent = ({ id }: MyComponentProps) => {
   ...
}
```

As far as I know Typescript doesn't allow you to use a Regex as a type. One of the solutions I found was declaring the type as something like
`` id: `${string}_${number}` ``, but that's not specific enough.

Is there any other way I could show some kind of warning if it does not match? Maybe using a linter or some other tool?

Comment: There are just a bit too many valid ids to fit in a TS union type, so the only approach that might work at compile time is to use a generic type that acts as a constraint, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w6Lg6m).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    import * as yup from 'yup';
    
    interface MyComponentProps {
      id: string;
    }
    const idSchema = yup.string().matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/);
    
    const MyComponent = ({ id }: MyComponentProps) => {
      try {
        idSchema.validateSync(id)
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid id: ${id}`);
      }
      // ...
    }
```

Yup is a JavaScript object schema validation library. It allows you to define a schema for an object, which describes the structure and types of the properties of the object, and then validate an object against that schema. It provides a simple, expressive way to validate objects, and it can also be used to ensure that the data you receive from user input or external sources meets certain constraints.

*In the code above, I've imported yup library and defined idSchema as a yup string schema that matches the given regex. And then I've used the validateSync method of yup to validate the id prop of the component against the schema. If the validation fails it throws an error.*

Note that this approach will only give you a warning at runtime, but it will not provide you with compile-time type checking.